# How to remove unwanted grey line at y = 0 in Excel 2016?

Tags: excel

I have created a scatterplot with lines and I removed all gridlines and chart borders. A line at y = 0 remains and I cannot select or remove it. What do I need to do to remove this line?
[image]

The following is a google drive link of a minimum reproducible sample if you want to download it. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bvHzTuN1OdYrwAGhoWWNfPDUgDTS2aks/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=113622331641410894876&rtpof=true&sd=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on the horizontal axis and format with no line:

[image]

Then if you click away from the graph:

[image]

I have only  tested it in Excel 365, the option may not be available in Excel 2016.